# Extract data from html table with dart

Tags: html, json, api, flutter, dart

There is a public web page that shows me information within three tables. I want to extract this information, but unfortunately I don't have an API for this, which I could use in my code. I thought about how this could best be solved and came to the conclusion that an analysis of the HTML code is unavoidable. So I would make an http get request and "cut" the data out of the response. One of the tables looks something like this

```
<table border="3" rules="all" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        <b>Mo</b>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        <b>Di</b>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        <b>Mi</b>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        <b>Do</b>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        <b>Fr</b>
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        7:35
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        8:20
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1" bgcolor="#010101">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#010101" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        WSP
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#010101" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        wü
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#010101" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        8k
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" width="33%" bgcolor="#010101" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial"
                                                                                   color="#FFFFFF">
                        A213
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        8:25
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        9:10
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="4" align="center" nowrap="1" bgcolor="#80FF80">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#80FF80" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        Phy
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#80FF80" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        mp
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#80FF80" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        8k
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" width="33%" bgcolor="#80FF80" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial"
                                                                                   color="#000000">
                        A236
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        9:15
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        10:00
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        10:20
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        11:05
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="4" align="center" nowrap="1" bgcolor="#8080FF">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#8080FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        G&amp;P
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#8080FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        hn
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#8080FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        8k
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" width="33%" bgcolor="#8080FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial"
                                                                                   color="#000000">
                        A312
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        11:10
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        11:55
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        12:00
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        12:45
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        12:55
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        13:40
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="4" align="center" nowrap="1" bgcolor="#8000FF">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#8000FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        Deu
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#8000FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        mu
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#8000FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">
                        8k
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" width="33%" bgcolor="#8000FF" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial"
                                                                                   color="#FFFFFF">
                        A413
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        13:45
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        14:30
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="4" align="center" nowrap="1" bgcolor="#FF8040">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#FF8040" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        MatS
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#FF8040" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        rm
                    </font></td>
                    <td width="33%" bgcolor="#FF8040" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        8k
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" width="33%" bgcolor="#FF8040" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial"
                                                                                   color="#000000">
                        A202
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">
                        15:35
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        16:20
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        16:25
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" nowrap="1"><font size="3" face="Arial">
                        17:10
                    </font></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="12" rowspan="2" align="center" nowrap="1" bgcolor="#0000A0">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I have a huge block from which I only want to filter out the following data.

[image]

I don't expect a ready-made solution, just a food for thought. I want to solve this problem with Dart and would treat all HTML as a string, whereupon I would cut this string and read the data from the resulting array.

Comment: are you using Dart on server side? Flutter/Dart on mobile clients?

Comment: Flutter/Dart on mobile clients

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla how does that make a difference in this context?

Comment: Dart on server side could require CORS enable in order to create a web crawler/scrapper. Mobile clients don't need that and are able to crawl websites. I'll give you an example in the answers.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Alright, thank you!

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Have you forgotten me? :(